# Shorter than expected receive using c# sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm using TCP sockets to communicate between two components of a project (both running locally). One acts as a server, processing data and sending messages to the other, acting as a client.

When sending from the server, I first send a 4-byte length header, followed by the message:

```
public void SendMessage(string message) {
    var binaryMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    var messageLength = binaryMessage.Length;
    var messageLengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(messageLength);

    _tcpClient.Client.Send(messageLengthBytes);
    var bytesSent = _tcpClient.Client.Send(binaryMessage);

    if (bytesSent != messageLength) {
        _log.Warn($"Incorrect byte count send ({bytesSent} instead of {messageLength}).");
    }
}
```

On the client side, when receiving, I read 4 bytes to get the length header, then read 4KB chunks until complete:

```
private const int RecBufferSize = 4096;
private readonly byte[] _recBuffer = new byte[RecBufferSize];

private void HandleNextIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult ar) {
    var bytesReceived = _tcp.Client.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesReceived != 4) {
        _log.Error("Could not figure out the size of the incoming message - forcing reconnect.");
        Reconnect();
        return;
    }

    var array = _recBuffer.Take(4).ToArray();
    var messageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 0);
    var messageBuffer = new byte[messageSize];
    var totalBytesFedIntoMessageBuffer = 0;

    while (totalBytesFedIntoMessageBuffer < messageSize) {
        var bytesToRead = messageSize - totalBytesFedIntoMessageBuffer;

        if (bytesToRead > RecBufferSize) {
            bytesToRead = RecBufferSize;
        }

        var bytesRead = _tcp.Client.Receive(_recBuffer, bytesToRead, SocketFlags.None);

        if (bytesRead != bytesToRead) {
            _log.Error($"Did not read the correct number of bytes {bytesToRead} from the network - read {bytesRead} - forcing reconnect.");
            Reconnect();
            return;
        }

        Buffer.BlockCopy(_recBuffer, 0, messageBuffer, totalBytesFedIntoMessageBuffer, bytesRead);

        totalBytesFedIntoMessageBuffer += bytesRead;
    }

    HandleMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBuffer));
}
```

Most messages are small (< 1KB), and never have any issues, but there is one particular message that carries a lot of data and can be 100-200KB in size. Most of the time it is send and received without issue, but occasionally a chunk doesn't contain the correct number of bytes and I see the log line `Did not read the correct number of bytes 4096 from the network - read 3472 - forcing reconnect.`.

As a strange aside, the number isn't always 3472, but frequently is.

Am I right in thinking that if I send data into the socket at the server end, and then call `Receive` at the client end, it should block until it receives the full 4096 bytes? If so then why would it receive a lesser byte count on occasion?

Comment: Does that message log on the last chunk received? That would happen if the payload wasn't exactly X chunks big, right? It wouldn't be an error in this case, it would just be the end of the stream.

Comment: The number of bytes to read for each chunk is calculated just inside the while block, so if there are > chunksize bytes still to read, take one chunk size (4096), otherwise take whatever is left. I've noticed it more often happening on the first chunk.

Comment: You should use the `bytesRead` instead of comparing it with the requested count. It's not a problem to receive less than the requested amount,

Comment: Why use a receive buffer with 4k if you already allocated the messagebuffer of x bytes? Use that buffer to receive the message. Requesting 200k from the socket is not a problem. You might receive less, but it will be received with the next request. There is an overload of the `socket.Receive()` method, so you can pass the start offset of the receive buffer to continue receiving. I would always reuse the receive buffer and construct a class that holds the message from it, so you can reuse the same bytebuffer. This prevents many allocations. (and blockcopies)

Comment: Even for as small a read as 4 bytes, to get the length, the data may have ended up fragmented across a packet boundary (TCP just delivers bytes) and so for all reads, you should be reading in a loop and using the returned values to know how much more to ask for, rather than trying to precalculate and *expect* that many bytes to be returned. And as Jeroen says, the imposition of this intermediate fixed-size buffer seems to offer no benefits here.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen / Damien - Thanks for the advice, I've updated the receive so that it uses the messageBuffer for reading into in the loop, and removed the bytesRead == bytesToRead check. I'll see how that behaves for me. I appreciate your replies!